# AutoMapper doesn't work in asp net core 5.0.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

I get an error which says I didn't register AutoMapper, but I did, and such configuration as listed below was used in another projects successfully:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'PromoAction.Services.Identity.API.Controllers.AccountController'

Please help me to figure out how to make it work in asp net core 5.

AutoMapperConfiguration.cs

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
   public MapperConfiguration Configure() => new(cfg =>
   {
       cfg.CreateMap<User, ClientDTO>();
       cfg.CreateMap<UserForRegistrationDto, User>()
            .ForMember(u => u.UserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Email))
            .ForMember(u => u.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Name))
            .ForMember(u => u.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Surname));
   });
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var config = new AutoMapperConfiguration().Configure().CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(sp => config);
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
public AccountController(IMapper mapper)
{
    this._mapper = mapper;
}
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0

Comment: AutoMapper works fine in .NET 5 -- they way you inject it is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recomended way of registering Autommaper is described in their docs: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Create mapping profile and register it using

```
services.AddAutoMapper(profileAssembly1, profileAssembly2 /*, ...*/);
```

In your case looks like you registered mapper instance, your example says that you injected mapper instance but exception says that you want to resolve IConfiguration. Check your code, if you don't try to inject IConfiguration (which is not registered).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not injecting automapper in a good way.

follow the following steps:

1. Install the nuget package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
2. Create a new automapper profile inherited  from Profile class ( remember to add using AutoMapper), example:

```
 public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {

            CreateMap<User, ClientDTO>();
            CreateMap<UserForRegistrationDto, User>()
                 .ForMember(u => u.UserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Email))
                 .ForMember(u => u.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Name))
                 .ForMember(u => u.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Surname));

        }
    }
```

In your startup class in the method configure services use AddAutoMapper and provide the typeof your startup

`services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));`

After that you can inject it normally

```
public AccountController(IMapper mapper)
{
    this._mapper = mapper;
}
```